# Animation nodes - Vertex colors to transforms?

Tags: animation-nodes, color, vertex-colors, vertex-weights

I apologize if this looks as spamming, but I think this should be a different question, though I am trying to achieve similar goal. I want to be able to influence matrices with several different drivers at the same time, but have a possibility to mask out specific objects if need be.

I found that I can create vertex color sets to use as masks for mixing materials, but I was wondering if I can use them for transforms as well?

As you can see in the image below I took the object group (this group is a smaller part of a bigger one) and am coloring it with driver with falloff. But since they have the separate smaller group it masks the drivers effects on the unwanted objects. Set vertex color node has an output of object. It seemas that I am unable to find a node wich could separate parts of that node and take only the vertex color part for me to plug in to animate matrix node.

So Can I extract colors back from the vertex color set?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the color using the following code:

```
object.data.vertex_colors[layerName].data[0].color
```

Where `object` is your object and `layerName` is your vertex color name.